# Excel VBA / Importing WMF image with default size result huge image

Tags: excel, vba

adding this same [question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_2016/importing-wmf-image-with-default-size-in-vba/886195f7-5612-4be1-b9d8-9f7af6d07068?tm=1613552446173) question to this forum as well.

Next behaviour started a few months ago in some computers after updates to Office / Excel.
Excel 2016 and 365 versions affected at least.

If you insert WMF image to excel using following macro,  (-1 means use the images default widht and height)  the image goes very, very big.
If you open the image in any other image application the size can be like 11cm * 10cm but in Excel it is like 800 cm * 558 cm.
(Other image formats are still working as excpected)

```
    Sub InsertPicture(picture As String)   
    Dim x As Integer
    x = ActiveWindow.Zoom
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
    Set p = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(picture, False, True, Selection.Left, Selection.Top, -1, -1)
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = x
    Set p = Nothing
End Sub
```

Example: Installed Office 2016 from ISO to empty virtual machine - WMF images was working. Installed all office updates, after that WMF was not working.

Seems to be so that Excel image import does calculate size correctly from Metafile header where dpiX and dpiY are in one example 8640 and Height is 25040 and width is 32760 --> size in Excel is 661cm * 866 cm

Comment: try set directly width and height of shape. first `dim p as shape` after add shape `p.width= x` and `shape.height = y `

Comment: >>try set directly width and height of shape

We use different size of images is same Excel position depending on Production options in another app. Currently we are converting WMF to PNG on the fly before calling VBA but this bug is annoying and affects our old app releases.

Comment: but you can add condition to set scale of picture for example if size of shape (width) > 2000 then set size 600 etc. You can select many cases of sizes. You can also try set pictureSizeMode 0,1,3 or create function maxWidth to check picture size after drawing and scale picture if some condiciots are met.